# stuck trying to randomly retrieve data from strings.xml

Tags: android, variables

I have a little app that i want to retrieve motivational quotes randomly. I have put them in the strings.xml file with names that are affirmation1, affirmation2 etc There will be hundreds eventually. I can't get what i want to work . Please help - this is my code, much appreciation for your time..

```
  Random random = new Random();
   // int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(4) + 1;
   String x = "R.string.affirmation"+randomNumber;
    //int id = getResources().getIdentifier(x, "string","au.org.meditation.affirmations");
    //String affirmationText = getResources().getString(id);
    String affirmationText = this.getString((x));
```

Comment: I have something like that. It's generalized and can be used for getting the id of an array,a string, a drawable, ... give me a minute, and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(affirmation"+randomNumber, "string", this.getPackageName());

String affirmationText = this.getString(drawableResourceId );
```

This will do but this might cause some slowness since it is using reflection.